# Neo4J: How load two billions of records from a csv?

Tags: import, neo4j, cypher, bigdata, neo4j-apoc

I'm trying to import data from csv with 2 billions of records into a Neo4J, now I'm using the following query (in my real query I have 40 properties and 5 type of nodes):

```
call apoc.periodic.commit("LOAD CSV with headers from 'file:///person_job.csv' as 
row fieldterminator '|' WITH row as a 
WHERE NOT a.id IS NULL
MERGE (b:Person{id:a.id})  
MERGE (c:Job{type:a.type})
MERGE (b)<-[:RELATED_TO]-(c)",{limit:2000000});
```

I created index on id and on type but now this query needs five days to finish.
Do you have any idea how to improve the efficiency of this query?

Answer (score 1):

If this is a one-time load or an initial load, you should use Neo4j-Import.
2M is a large commit. Ensure you have a large HEAP size to handle that.

Comment: How could i have a periodic commit, without to use the command 'USING PERIODIC COMMIT' ?